# How to get Vim in cygwin/Windows to underline the CursorLine properly?

Tags: vim, cygwin, vimrc

Here is a portion of my .vimrc :

```
set background=dark
set cul
hi CursorLine term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline
```

On Linux, vim displays fine and the cursor line is underlined with a thin white line. Using the same .vimrc file on Windows (under cygwin), the cursor line has a dark red background instead of being underlined. No amount of playing with `hi CursorLine` seems to do the trick. Is there a way to underline the current line on Cygwin/Windows or is that a limitation of the Windows command window?

Comment: What is your version of Cygwin and VIM?  Those commands as given work fine for Cygwin 1.7.9-1 + Vim 7.3 running within `mintty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a failing in the Windows console; it has no way to render underlined text, but uses colors instead.

With an XTerm or other terminal software the underlining should work fine as long as you have

```
:set cursorline
```

Comment: You are right. I use minTTY now and it looks fine. Thanks.